# How to add a user account for the app in iOS and store sessionId from server

Tags: ios, iphone, rubymotion

I'm trying to create a simple login/signup app that allows the users put in their email address and password. If the authentication is successful, I want to add the my app name to the phone's settings screen. Similar to what Twitter, facebook, etc do.

I've got authentication working fine with the server but I don't know how to add my app name to the phone's settings page and store the sessionID returned from the server so that I can reuse it in future requests to the server.

Answer (score 0):

**Storing information** on the device can be easily done using `NSUserDefaults`. Assuming your `sessionID` is an NSString:

**Storing:**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:sessionID forKey:@"SessionID"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**Retrieving:**

```
NSString *sessionID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SessionID"]
```

However, sensible information like a Session ID should be stored in a protected space, such as the keychain; see [Apple's documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1).

Adding your application to the device's **settings menu** can be achieved by adding a `Settings.bundle` to your project. See [Apple's documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html).